# Flutter webview package inline media problem

Tags: flutter, webview, webview-flutter

webview_flutter 1.0.7 using your package.
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/3334/commits/1d7e5ebab3c86bf5f2bf252ae14bca87be33c414
I made the changes on the page. Although I made all the changes, the ipad is working in full screen but the iphone does not work

sample videos as below
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/57063848/104122686-8abf8700-5357-11eb-96b4-beb18cc5c4e1.mov

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/57063848/104122691-901cd180-5357-11eb-9dcc-aa6b842263de.mov

sample code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: WebView(
          initialUrl: "https://www.medivizyon.com.tr/in5",
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          initialMediaPlaybackPolicy: AutoMediaPlaybackPolicy.always_allow,
          allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

flutter doctor -v

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2 darwin-x64, locale tr-TR)
    • Flutter version 1.22.5 at /Users/gokhan/flutter
    • Framework revision 7891006299 (4 weeks ago), 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
    • Engine revision ae90085a84
    • Dart version 2.10.4

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/gokhan/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.3, Build version 12C33
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 46.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.18.1
```

pubspec.yaml

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.8.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  webview_flutter: ^1.0.7
  
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
```

Answer (score 0):

pythoneer commented yesterday

What is the current state of this issue? Flutter 2 is stable and released and the same is true for webview_flutter in version 2.0.2 . I can see changes being made to allow this

```
} else if ([key isEqualToString:@"allowsInlineMediaPlayback"]) {
  NSNumber* allowsInlineMediaPlayback = settings[key];
  _webView.configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = [allowsInlineMediaPlayback boolValue];
} else {
```

But i don't have the desired effect. It is still not working as described in this issue. If i fork this and apply the changes manually

```
WKWebViewConfiguration* configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
configuration.userContentController = userContentController;
[self updateAutoMediaPlaybackPolicy:args[@"autoMediaPlaybackPolicy"]
                    inConfiguration:configuration];

configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;
```

it is working as expected.